# Search multiple columns for string to set indicator variable

Tags: r

I am using R and RStudio for the first time to work with a very large dataset (15 million cases) with many columns of data.  To facilitate analysis, I need to search a range of columns row-wise to see if any match specific strings (there are about 200 strings to match, would be in another dataframe).

The data looks like this

```
  Dx1     Dx2     Dx3   etc... 
  001     234     456 
  231     001     444
  245     777     001
```

What is needed is

```
Dx1     Dx2     Dx3  Var001   Var234  Var456  Var231   etc..   
001     234     456  True     True    True    False
231     001     444  True     False   False   True
245     777     001  True     False   False   False
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Be aware that row-wise operations tend to be quite slow with data.frames. If your columns are all numeric (or all three digit characters), you might be better off working with matrices. Further, if this holds, you might consider transposing the matrix and then run column-level operations which are more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea using base R with `lapply`:

```
uniq_dxs <- as.character(unique(melt(df1, id.vars = NULL)$value))
df1[, paste0("var", uniq_dxs)] <- lapply(uniq_dxs, function(x) rowSums(df1==x) > 0)

df1
#  Dx1 Dx2 Dx3 var001 var231 var245 var234 var777 var456 var444
#1 001 234 456   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
#2 231 001 444   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
#3 245 777 001   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
```

---

Benchmark on my machine since I was curious. Just wanted to compare the `mtabulate` to the `lapply`. Not including the `<-`:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(mtab = mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1)))!=0,
                               lapply = lapply(uniq_dxs, function(x) rowSums(df1==x) > 0))
Unit: microseconds
   expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
   mtab 1039.317 1088.9120 1182.3375 1109.334 1145.255 5931.031   100
 lapply  742.838  795.7155  823.7991  813.220  843.488 1034.211   100
```

Comment: Not pure base R, because you're using `reshape2::melt`. But seems to work. Also you left out the fragment where you find unique values from your benchmark, I've added that to my benchmarks below.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
library(qdapTools)
res <- cbind(df1, mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1)))!=0)
row.names(res) <- NULL
names(res)[-(1:3)] <- paste0("Var", names(res)[-(1:3)])
res
#  Dx1 Dx2 Dx3 Var001 Var234 Var456 Var231 Var444 Var245 Var777
#1 001 234 456   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
#2 231 001 444   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
#3 245 777 001   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Dx1 = c("001", "231", "245"), Dx2 = c("234", "001", 
"777"), Dx3 = c("456", "444", "001")), .Names = c("Dx1", "Dx2", 
"Dx3"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can implement a reusable function, in only a few lines of code, but requires some knowledge about which functions to use and how.

I'll call the function `bag`, as in bag-of-words.

```
bag <- function(..., prefix=".", levels=NULL, `NA`=NULL) {

  # Go from multiple columns to list of vectors
  bags <- mapply(c, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

  # Find unique levels
  if(is.null(levels)) {
    levels <- sort(Reduce(union, bags))

    # names persist through outer
    names(levels) <- paste0(prefix, levels)
  }

  # Calculate out[level,bag] = level %in% bag 
  out <- outer(levels, bags, Vectorize(`%in%`))

  # Output a data structure
  structure(+t(out), class='bag', levels=levels)
}
```

Which would let us do:

```
with(df1, bag(Dx1, Dx2, Dx3, prefix="Var"))
#>      Var001 Var231 Var234 Var245 Var444 Var456 Var777
#> [1,]      1      0      1      0      0      1      0
#> [2,]      1      1      0      0      1      0      0
#> [3,]      1      0      0      1      0      0      1
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "bag"
#> attr(,"levels")
#> Var001 Var231 Var234 Var245 Var444 Var456 Var777 
#>  "001"  "231"  "234"  "245"  "444"  "456"  "777"
```

This is probably not very performant, but it works. I've changed the output format from logical to numeric and included some metadata to make it easier to use in a model. We can add a function to enable modeling with bag directly:

```
#' @export
makepredictcall.bag <- function(var, call){
  # Stolen from splines package
  if (as.character(call)[1L] != "bag")
    return(call)
  args <- c("prefix", "levels")


  at <- attributes(var)[args]
  xxx <- call
  xxx[args] <- NULL
  xxx[names(at)] <- at
  xxx
}
```

Now, you can use it directly in a model formula. This has the advantage that the dummy coding is now incorporated in to the model and you won't need to preprocess
when predicting on new data sets. Example:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df1, sample, 20, TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df3 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df1, sample, 20, TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Y <- 1:nrow(df2)
m <- lm(Y~bag(Dx1, Dx2, Dx3), df2)
summary(m)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Y ~ bag(Dx1, Dx2, Dx3), data = df2)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -8.1110 -3.6765  0.1948  3.1899  8.7961 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)             16.6709    10.3948   1.604    0.135
#> bag(Dx1, Dx2, Dx3).001  -3.7385     5.6141  -0.666    0.518
#> bag(Dx1, Dx2, Dx3).231  -3.7286     4.1728  -0.894    0.389
#> bag(Dx1, Dx2, Dx3).234   3.1786     4.6528   0.683    0.507
#> bag(Dx1, Dx2, Dx3).245  -7.2493     4.4900  -1.615    0.132
#> bag(Dx1, Dx2, Dx3).444  -2.2936     4.3033  -0.533    0.604
#> bag(Dx1, Dx2, Dx3).456   2.9979     4.3826   0.684    0.507
#> bag(Dx1, Dx2, Dx3).777  -0.8608     4.5353  -0.190    0.853
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 5.971 on 12 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.3566, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.01874 
#> F-statistic: 0.9501 on 7 and 12 DF,  p-value: 0.5056
predict(m, df3)
#>         1         2         3         4         5         6         7 
#>  8.681003 16.111016  4.822329 15.079445 19.108899 10.306611 13.817465 
#>         8         9        10        11        12        13        14 
#> 16.111016  9.788011 12.382454  9.778103  3.389569 12.382454  9.203882 
#>        15        16        17        18        19        20 
#> 13.817465  9.788011 12.071654  6.267249 13.827373 15.069537
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

EDIT:

And some benchmarks for comparison

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(mtab = mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1)))!=0,
                               lapply = lapply(as.character(unique(melt(df1, id.vars = NULL)$value)), 
                                               function(x) rowSums(df1==x) > 0),
                               bag = do.call(bag, df1))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>    expr     min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>    mtab 439.320 452.107 519.9429 462.9035 511.8710 1960.582   100
#>  lapply 276.914 295.976 337.6020 300.7870 315.0135 2268.210   100
#>     bag 121.996 130.305 146.6677 139.6990 145.3275  294.711   100
```